# expect + how to install expect on solaris

Tags: bash, solaris, shell-scripting, expect, tcl

subject - install expect on solaris in order to write expect scripts

details from my machine:

uname -a
SunOS 5.10 Generic_139555-08 sun4v sparc SUNW,Netra-T5220

I installed Solaris machine (  Solaris 10 ) , and then I installed successfully the following packages in order to build the expect infrastructure on my Solaris machine

But after packages installation I get the following errors

Please advice what needed in order to run expect ?

```
  1)

  /usr/local/bin/expect   -version
  /usr/local/bin/expect: cannot execute

  2)

  expect
  expect: not found
```

Example how to install expect for Solaris ( from site - http://jibbysununix.blogspot.com/2010/01/automating-sftp-with-expect-script.html )

( I downloaded the x86packages from sun freeware )
.
    tcl-8.5.3-sol10-x86-local
    libgcc-3.4.6-sol10-x86-local
    expect-5.43.0-sol10-x86-local

```
   1)pkgadd -d tcl-8.5.3-sol10-x86-local

   2)pkgadd -d libgcc-3.4.6-sol10-x86-local

   3)pkgadd -d expect-5.43.0-sol10-x86-local
```

Comment: Also asked on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10596626/7552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You arent trying to run x86 software on sparc are you?

```
uname -a
```

Uninstall the x86 packages and download and install sparc from:

http://www.sunfreeware.com/indexsparc10.html

To uninstall packages:

```
pkginfo | grep SMC
```

You'll see the three packages you installed, sunfreeware packages always have the SMC prefix, use pkgrm to remove them

Comment: see update in my quastion

Comment: You are running sparc, therefore x86 packages wont work, immediately uninstall these packages, and download and install the solaris 10 sparc counterparts.

Comment: did you know from where - wwhich site I can download the sparc pkgs as expect and tcl etc...

Comment: Yes, ive added the like to my answer. Sunfreeware has both x86 and sparc packages.

Comment: so according to your link I need to install the pkgs - expect-5.45-sol10-sparc-local.gz
tcl-8.5.10
libgcc-3.4.6
this is true ?

Comment: Thats what it says, it also says that coreutils is required... coreutils requires libiconv, libintl, gmp ...  Follow the dependancies, install everything thats required.

Answer (score 0):

There are other sources of Solaris packages, for example OpenCSW. They provide tools to perform automatic dependency resolution, and will make sure to download the right architecture.

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
pkgutil -U
pkgutil -y -i expect
```

Executables will be placed in `/opt/csw/bin`, e.g. `/opt/csw/bin/expect`.